# Proper install NVIDIA drivers

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary

i have a problem and i want to get rid of it.

I have a EVGA 480 GTX graphic card and i can't install the proprietary drivers.

I tried lots of distro, its everytime the same problem : TTY console or poor graphics ( no shadow, no mice, i can just open a term via Ctrl+Alt+T)

I need NVIDIA propietary drivers :<

Could you tell me a proper way to install nvidia drivers ?

Thank you,

Johnny

Comment: Perhaps you just need to configure the current driver... Try `aptitude install nvidia-settings` and then `nvidia-settings` and then follow the instructions. Or use `apt-get` if you don't have `aptitude`.

Answer (score 0):

The most up-to-date proprietary Nvidia drivers are the experimental builds, which you should be able to find in the **Additional Drivers** section of the **Software Sources** control panel as described here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve#NVIDIA_Graphics

> 1. In 12.04, launch the Additional Hardware Drivers dialog from System Settings. In 12.10, launch Software Sources, then click on the Additional Drivers tab in the Software Sources menu.
> 2. Install the newest nvidia-experimental-NNN driver. Note that you probably will need to scroll down to see the experimental drivers.

I'm not sure if this is applicable to your particular card and chipset, but this is what I'm currently using with my GTX 560 (I've selected the nvidia-experimental-310 option).